# Tomcat/https: I can see compression is enabled, but file sizes are the same as without compression

Tags: https, compression, gzip, safari

I have enabled compression on Tomcat running on my machine. The https response header is showing compression is enabled, but the same amount of data is being transferred with and without compression turned on.

## Without compression:

```
Status OK
Code    200
Encoded 218.89 KB
Decoded 218.89 KB
Transfered  219.22 KB
Compressed  No
```

## With compression:

```
Status  OK
Code    200
Encoded 218.89 KB
Decoded 218.89 KB
Transfered  219.26 KB
Compressed  Yes
Compression 1.00×
```

I can see Content-Encoding as gzip in response header.

My connector definition in server.xml follows:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="xxxxx" keystorePass="xxxx"
           useSendfile="false" compression="force" />
```

I am using Tomcat 8.0.12. Browsers are latest versions of Safari running on MAC OS X Yosemite.

[Detailed info with compression ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHj9K.png)

[Detailed info with compression OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPbJ9.png)

**Edit**: As per Tim's answer, I was misled by the Safari reporting numbers. See [stackoverflow.com/a/21943693/3944823](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21943693/3944823.).

Comment: what is your compressionMinSize ? also, compression + https = danger

Comment: It is the default "2048" bytes. I tried explicitly setting it to "2048" and also a very low value "3" with no changes in results. Thanks for the heads up on the vulnerability this opens, but I am willing to explore the benefits of compression.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Tomcat that's not working? It could be that the web browser is incorrectly reporting content size rather than transfer size. Check it with another web browser, or check the web server access logs.

Comment: @Tim: You're right! Checking in Chrome clearly shows the content is being compressed (Network->Size column). For each applicable file, it shows the "size" (what's transferred on the wire) is much smaller than the "content".

Comment: Knowing now it is a Safari thing, I see this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21943693/3944823. The second answer nails the reason why I was on a wrong path.

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer so you can accept it, so others don't have to spend time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's Tomcat that's not working? It could be that the web browser is incorrectly reporting content size rather than transfer size. Check it with another web browser, or check the web server access logs.

Note - confirmed as per comments above.